# I have a sheet with a multiple columns I want to copy the certain columns based on condition from sheet and paste the data as per location

Tags: vba, excel

For Example in data sheet column named location have different location. so I want to copy the certain column based on location. ex if location = "A" then all data will be copy to sheet "A".

```
NAME         DOB       LOCATION PROGRAM Roll no
Rahul        5/19/1993  A         MD    45
Rohit        12/25/1964 B         DD    74
Kaushal      6/22/1985  C         FF    41
XYZ          12/7/1975  D         DD    78
AB           5/31/1990  E         AA    44
AB           4/25/1977  F         VV    45
B            7/2/1972   G         CC    44
D            9/23/1985  H         ZZ    44
```

Comment: I have tried to record the macro for this:

Comment: Loop through all data rows. For each row, get column Location value as variable, and copy to desired sheet (using the created variable for this).

Answer (score 0):

In a rush right now for polishing the code, but try something like this:

```
Dim lLastRow As Long
Dim i, k As Integer
Dim SheetName As String

Private Sub CopyData()
lLastRow = Worksheets("Data").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To lLastRow
    SheetName = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3)
    k = Worksheets(SheetName).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(k, 1) = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1)
Next
End Sub
```